# Swift: restoring UIView center after moving it

Tags: ios, swift, value-type

I'm using gestures to zoom and move a UIImageView (like Instagram zoom, for example). When the gesture ends, I want to restore UIImageView initial position, but I cannot get a copy of the initial center because it's a reference type. Using:

```
let prevCenter = myImage.center
```

is of course useless. How can I copy it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On zoom and move apply `transform` to view. On the end just set `.identity` value.

**Edit**

Example:

```
@IBOutlet weak var butt: UIButton!

var offsetTransform: CGAffineTransform = .identity
var zoomTransform: CGAffineTransform = .identity

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onPan(pan:)))
    pan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2
    pan.delegate = self
    view.addGestureRecognizer(pan)

    let pinch = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onPinch(pinch:)))
    pinch.delegate = self
    view.addGestureRecognizer(pinch)
}

@objc func onPinch(pinch: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    let s = pinch.scale
    zoomTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: s, y: s)
    butt.transform = offsetTransform.concatenating(zoomTransform)
    if (pinch.state == .ended) {
        finish()
    }
}

@objc func onPan(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let t = pan.translation(in: view)
    offsetTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: t.x, y: t.y)
}

func updatePos() {
    butt.transform = offsetTransform.concatenating(zoomTransform)
}

func finish() {
    butt.transform = .identity
}

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: I'm using two different gestures (pinch and pan). As regards pan gesture, I'm just explicitly setting the center of the view, so I'm not applying transform. Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you are not updating the `prevCenter` somewhere else?
`center` is struct so you shouldn't have problems copying it.

Just make sure to take it (the center) when the view is in original state, before starting to zoom it and after it is drawn with correct frame

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20))

let prevCenter = view.center // 20, 20

imageView.center = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50)

// imageView.center - 50, 50
// prevCenter - 20, 20

imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 10, height: 10)
// imageView.center - 45, 45
// prevCenter - 20, 20
```

Comment: You are right, I was accidentally updating prevCenter when gesture callback was called... shame on me